# Long float number using PHP

Tags: php

I have the number `2.23456789`, I want to get it only 2.23 by using PHP,but I do not know how to do this, anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: Why not just Google - PHP rounding numbers?

Comment: You want to chop the number after 2 decimals, round the number after 2 decimals, you want to display the number with upto 2 decimal places? What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `round(value,precision)` function.
In your case, use:

```
round(2.23456789,2);
```

For further information check the PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: I think you should fix your link, just remove the spacing before http.

Answer (score 0):

You simply want to [`round`](http://php.net/round) the number.

Answer (score 0):

Use phps [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.